# Rails, placing Ruby variable's into Javascript for Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, struct, google-visualization

hi i am wondering if anyone has played with google charts before its great for the lazy programmer to pump up his analytic's in any site. i am very new to javascript in fact today was my first day using it. so i have some javascript from google that generates these charts to insert the base data it supplies you with bare bones, in javascript like this:

```
// Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Velocity');
    data.addRows([
      ['Gary', 9],
      ['Hannes', 11],
      ['Sandra', 5],
      ['Rob', 3],
```

this is all between < script > tags. now i am just playing with it. but having static data in here is about useful as a hole in a boat. how could i append the numbers with say this haml table i made:

```
%table.gap
  - test = sprint.work_by_developer
  %tr
    - test.each do |data|
      %td.column.developer_name
        = data.name
        \:
      %td.type_of_work
        Features:
        %span.indicator_color
          #{data.features} points
        %br/
        Chores: 
        %span.indicator_color
          = data.chores
        %br/
        bugs:
        %span.indicator_color
          = data.bugs
```

is it possible to loop through the javascript do something like this:

```
......
      [data.name, data.features],
      ])
```

so that if new people join in the team or the amount of features changes on the fly the chart will adjust in real time??

cool, thanks in advance. this would be a really cool feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need to do is do string manipulation (usually templating) to make ruby output a valid JavaScript source file to be sent over to the client and be rendered using Google Charts.

The Javascript you are emitting has to be processed by Ruby for it to work.

If you are using Ruby on Rails there is the excellent way to do that via the `respond_to` keyword where you can specify a different output for different formats (json/xml/html/js).

If you are using Rails you can simply define a action method like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def Show
    @data = [["harry", 10], ["sue", 19]]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

You then have to have a file called `show.js.erb` inside app/views/home that looks like this:

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Velocity');
    <% @data.each do |d| %>
    data.addRow(['<%= @d[0] %>', <%= @d[1] %>]);
    <% end %>
```

You then go ahead an at the point where you want this data you simply insert your `<script>` tag to point to that home/show.js action:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/show.js" />
```

This will then execute the home#show action (**in a new request mind you**) and bring back the data into your page.

***OR***:

You could simply output a  tag in your view with data filled from the current request like you would with any other view stuff (i just can't tell you how you do that in HAML)

Comment: yip i am using rails3. yeah i reckon i should take a day and read up some javascript books. and ill read up on     respond_to it looks quite powerful.

Comment: You can also optionally set respond_to :html, :js at the top of the file and have the show method respond_with @data

Answer (score 1):

Now, there's a gem to conveniently transfers your variable to view's javascript: gon.
https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: Very cool spent the last hour or so reading up on it. thanks!